# SignalR with MySQL server and Xamarin Client stops working after several successful invokes

Tags: android, mysql, xamarin, signalr

I'm creating an android app in Visual Studios Xamarin using SignalR, MySQL, and IIS. I've spent many hours trying to find a solution and can't find anything. Basically I have a database of users and an app that signs them in, out, and up. The app works several times, logging in, out, and signing up users, but eventually hangs, no exception is thrown, the app is still interactive with the exception of performing any interaction with the backend. I've checked my stacktrace with no luck, it seems to attempt to connect and then nothing happens. Initially all the user interaction was in a dialog fragment, so I tried them in their own activities and still receive the same error. I first started this with a Microsoft SQL server as it did the same thing, hoping it was some dumb MS security thing I switched to MySQL with no luck. I've turned off my firewall with no luck and checked all of my IIS settings. I've built apps in the past using this same basic setup and never encountered this before and have had no luck remedying it.

Client: Main Activity

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using ChipTracker.Objects;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Views;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using Android.Content;
using MySql.Data;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ChipTracker
{
    [Activity(Label = "ChipTracker", MainLauncher = true, Theme =         "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar", ScreenOrientation =     ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]
public class MainActivity : Activity, IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListener
{
    private Button btnSignUp, btnSignIn;
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    ListView userListView;
    public IHubProxy RemoteHubProxy;
    public HubConnectionTask hubConnection;
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);            
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionTask();
        RemoteHubProxy = await hubConnection.HubConnection();            
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        userListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.onlineUsersListView);
        btnSignUp = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSignUp);
        btnSignUp.Click += BtnSignUp_Click;
        btnSignIn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSignIn);
        btnSignIn.Click += BtnSignIn_Click;
        int uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
        Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;

        GetWhoseOnline();
    }

    private void BtnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        dialog_SignIn signInDialog = new dialog_SignIn();
        signInDialog.Show(transaction, "signin fragment");

    }

    private void BtnSignUp_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SignUpActivity));
        this.StartActivity(intent);
        this.Finish();
    }

    public async void GetWhoseOnline()
    {  
        RemoteHubProxy.On<List<User>>("whosOnline", (receivedList) =>
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                users = receivedList;
                UserAdapter userAdapter = new UserAdapter(this, users);
                userListView.Adapter = userAdapter;
            });
        });
        await RemoteHubProxy.Invoke("WhosOnline");


    }

    public void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
    {
        GetWhoseOnline();
    }


}
}
```

Client: HubConnection

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using ChipTracker.Objects;

namespace ChipTracker
{
    public class HubConnectionTask
    {
        string address = "http://192.168.100.12/PokerBackend/";
        public async Task<IHubProxy> HubConnection()
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Connection Start");
            var hubConnection = new HubConnection(address);
           hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
           hubConnection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;
            var remoteHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("RemoteHub"); 
            try
            {
                await hubConnection.Start();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            return remoteHubProxy;
        }
}
```

Client: Sign In Dialog

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.Views.Animations;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using ChipTracker.Objects;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

namespace ChipTracker
{
    class dialog_SignIn : DialogFragment
    {
        public IHubProxy RemoteHubProxy;
        private EditText txtUserName;
        private EditText txtPin;
        private TextView txtError;
        private Button btnSignIn;
        private RelativeLayout box;
        public Animation shake;
        public HubConnectionTask hubConnection;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_sign_in, container, false);
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionTask();
            txtError = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textDialogErrorSignIn);
            txtUserName = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtUserNameSignIn);
            txtPin = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPinSignIn);            
            btnSignIn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDialogSignIn);
            btnSignIn.Click += BtnSignIn_Click;
            box = view.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.dialogBoxSignIn);
            return view;
        }

        private async void BtnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            User user = new User();

                if (txtPin.Text != "")
                {
                    RemoteHubProxy = await hubConnection.HubConnection();
                    user.pin = Convert.ToInt32(txtPin.Text);
                    if (txtUserName.Text == "")
                    {
                        txtError.Text = "Username is blank.";
                        shake = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(Application.Context, Resource.Animation.shake);
                        box.StartAnimation(shake);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user.username = txtUserName.Text;
                        user.online = "y";
                        user.start_time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm MM/dd");
                        LoginUser(user);

                }
                }
                else
                {

                    txtError.Text = "Pin is blank.";
                    shake = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(Application.Context, Resource.Animation.shake);
                    box.StartAnimation(shake);
                }


        }




        private async void LoginUser(User user)
        {
            RemoteHubProxy = await hubConnection.HubConnection();
            try
            {
                RemoteHubProxy.On<String>("loginUserSuccess", (success) =>
                {



                        Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                        {
                            if (success == "y")
                            {

                                this.Dismiss();
                            }
                            if (success == "n" || success == null)
                            {
                                txtError.Text = "Unsuccessful Login. Please try again.";
                                shake = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(Application.Context, Resource.Animation.shake);
                                box.StartAnimation(shake);
                            }



                        });
                 });

                    await RemoteHubProxy.Invoke("LoginAsync", new object[] { user });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        public override void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
        {
            hubConnection.EndHubConnection();
            base.OnDismiss(dialog);
            Activity activity = this.Activity;
            ((IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListener)activity).OnDismiss(dialog);
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation;
        }

    }
}
```

SignalR Server: RemoteHub

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Renci.SshNet;
using PokerBackend.Objects;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace PokerBackend
{
    public class RemoteHub : Hub
    {


        public void WhosOnline()
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localConnection"].ConnectionString);
            List<User> userList = new List<User> { };
            MySqlCommand MySqlCommandSelect = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE isLoggedIn='y' AND isAdmin='n'", conn);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = MySqlCommandSelect.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                User user = new User();
                user.username = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(0));
                user.pin = Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetValue(1));
                userList.Add(user);
            }
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
            Clients.All.whosOnline(userList);

        }
        public void CreateUser (User user)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localConnection"].ConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand MySqlCommandCreate = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO user_table (user_name, pin, isAdmin, isLoggedIn, start_time) VALUES (@username, @pin, @isAdmin, @isLoggedIn, @start_time)", conn);
            MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.username);
            MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", Convert.ToInt32(user.pin));
            MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isAdmin", user.admin);
            MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isLoggedIn", user.online);
            MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_time", user.start_time);
            // MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end_time", user.end_time);
            //MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_time", user.total_time);
            //MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rewards", user.rewards);
            conn.Open();
            try
            {                
                MySqlCommandCreate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Clients.All.createUserSuccess("y");

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Clients.All.createUserSuccess("n");

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        public void Logout (User user)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localConnection"].ConnectionString);
            User userDB = new User();
            MySqlCommand MySqlCommandLogout = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE user_table SET isLoggedIn = 'n', end_time = @end_time WHERE user_name = @username", conn);
            MySqlCommandLogout.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.username);
            //MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", user.pin);
            //MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isAdmin", user.admin);
            MySqlCommandLogout.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isLoggedIn", "n");
            MySqlCommandLogout.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end_time", user.end_time);
            conn.Open();
            try
            {

                MySqlCommandLogout.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Clients.All.logoutUserSuccess("y");


            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Clients.All.logoutUserSuccess("n");
                Console.WriteLine(ex);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Clients.All.logoutUserSuccess("n");

            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }


        public void LoginAsync(User user)
        {
            User userDB = new User();
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localConnection"].ConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand MySqlCommandSelect = new MySqlCommand("", conn);
            conn.Open();

            try
            {
                MySqlCommandSelect = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE user_name=@username AND pin=@pin", conn);
                MySqlCommandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.username);
                MySqlCommandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", user.pin);

                MySqlDataReader reader = MySqlCommandSelect.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    userDB.username = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(0));       //user_name
                    userDB.pin = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(1));       //pin
                    //userDB.admin = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(2)); // isAdmin
                    userDB.online = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(3));  //isLoggedIn
                    //userDB.start_time = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(4));  //start_time
                    //userDB.end_time = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(5));   //end_time
                    //userDB.total_time = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(6));   //total_time
                    //userDB.rewards = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(7));       //rewards             
                }

                reader.Close();
                if (userDB.online == "y")
                {
                    Clients.All.loginUserSuccess("n");

                }



                if (user.pin == userDB.pin && userDB.online == "n")
                {
                    MySqlCommand MySqlCommandLogin = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE user_table SET isLoggedIn='y', start_time=@start_time WHERE user_name=@username", conn);
                    MySqlCommandLogin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.username);
                    //MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", user.pin);
                    //MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isAdmin", user.admin);
                    //MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isLoggedIn", user.online);
                    MySqlCommandLogin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_time", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm MM/dd"));
                    //MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end_time", user.end_time);
                    //MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_time", user.total_time);
                    //MySqlCommandCreate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rewards", user.rewards);
                    MySqlCommandLogin.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Clients.All.loginUserSuccess("y");

                }
                if (user.pin != userDB.pin)
                {
                    Clients.All.loginUserSuccess("n");

                }



            }

            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Clients.All.loginUserSuccess("n");
                Console.WriteLine(ex);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Clients.All.loginUserSuccess("n");
                Console.WriteLine(e);

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }



        }


    }
}
```

I know everything is being passed in plain text, I'm adding encryption once I get this working. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I should also add I've tried this on different android devices and emulators, different Windows machines for the backend, and different networks.

Comment: If you have two phones running simultaneously, do they both become unresponsive together or separately? The first would imply a server issue, the second an app issue.

Comment: They both become unresponsive at the same time. So a server issue? My code works, updates to the database are happening and pulling info works as well. Are there any security settings that MySQL and MSSQL share that may be preventing this? Maybe IIS?